# how to add tags in react.js semantic ui in select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

i am working on react select-option modal and i am stuck in code, i want used react-semantic-ui for design,i want select or div with description .

CODE:

```
  let permissions = [
      { key: 1, value: 1, text: 'Owner',tags:'Can fully configure and edit anything, manage workspaces and billing' },
      { key: 2, value: 2, text: 'Creator',tags:'Can completely configure a stack' },
      { key: 3, value: 3, text: 'Editor',tags:'Can only edit rows, cannot configure tables or columns' },
      { key: 4, value: 4, text: 'Commenter',tags:'Can only comment on rows' },
      { key: 5, value: 5, text: 'Read only',tags:'Cannot edit anything, only read' }
    ];
console.log(permissions);
```

i want to display **value,text with tag,**

```
let permissions = [
          { key: 1, value: 1, text: 'Owner',tags:'Can fully configure and edit anything, manage workspaces and billing' },
          { key: 2, value: 2, text: 'Creator',tags:'Can completely configure a stack' },
          { key: 3, value: 3, text: 'Editor',tags:'Can only edit rows, cannot configure tables or columns' },
          { key: 4, value: 4, text: 'Commenter',tags:'Can only comment on rows' },
          { key: 5, value: 5, text: 'Read only',tags:'Cannot edit anything, only read' }
        ];
```

i want output like this image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added string value in the tag, instead of this you can use **content** property and specify the component that you want to render. Like **Header** will be a perfect fit as per your requirement. Here I have mapped your permission array, but you can update your existing array of permission with component property instead of the tag.

```
const options = permissions.map((x) => ({
  key: x.key,
  text: x.text,
  value: x.key,
  content: <Header content={x.text} subheader={x.tags} />
}));

const DropdownExampleItemContent = () => (
  <Dropdown selection fluid options={options} placeholder="Choose an option" />
);
```

Here is its Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-y6zls